# @ Html.ActionLink can send with id and see id in other view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to go to this adres. In the project, we create a survey first. then click that button next to the survey to see the survey's questions.

[Survey's List. And "Soruları Gör" is that button.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QBPI.png)

When the button is clicked, we go to the other controller's index page. Like this,
[Survey's Questions' Index Page. Click on the button in the box to add a new question to the survey.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jG4qx.png)

I want to send the survey's id to the new question page and show it on that page. 
[new question creation page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXR8a.png)

I want the survey's Id to come in the red box in the picture 3.

```
This view belongs to the 2nd picture. 

@model IEnumerable<PerformansTakipAnket.Models.View_Base_UyeAnketSorular_Getir>

        @{
            ViewBag.Title = "Index";
        }

        <h2>Index</h2>

        <p>

            @Html.ActionLink("Yeni Soru", "Create")

        </p>
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UyeAnketID)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.uyeAnketSoruID)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UyeAnketSoruTip)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UyeAnketSoruUstID)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.uyeAnketSoruBaslik)
                </th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model) {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UyeAnketID)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.uyeAnketSoruID)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UyeAnketSoruTip)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UyeAnketSoruUstID)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.uyeAnketSoruBaslik)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Cevapları Gör", "Index", "Cevap", new { id = item.uyeAnketSoruID }, null) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.uyeAnketSoruID }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.uyeAnketSoruID })


                </td>
            </tr>
        }

        </table>
```

---

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
        {
            var sorular = db.View_Base_UyeAnketSorular_Getir.Where(i => i.UyeAnketID == id);
            ViewBag.UyeAnketID = id;

            return View(sorular.ToList());
        }

// GET: Soru/Create
        public ActionResult Create(int id)
        {


            @ViewBag.UyeAnketID = id;


            return View();
        }

        // POST: Soru/Create

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "uyeAnketSoruID,UyeAnketID,UyeAnketSoruTip,UyeAnketSoruUstID,uyeAnketSoruBaslik")] View_Base_UyeAnketSorular_Getir view_Base_UyeAnketSorular_Getir)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                db.Proc_UyeAnketSorular_EkleGuncelleSil("YeniKayit", view_Base_UyeAnketSorular_Getir.uyeAnketSoruID, view_Base_UyeAnketSorular_Getir.UyeAnketID, view_Base_UyeAnketSorular_Getir.UyeAnketSoruTip, view_Base_UyeAnketSorular_Getir.UyeAnketSoruUstID, view_Base_UyeAnketSorular_Getir.uyeAnketSoruBaslik);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index", new { @id = view_Base_UyeAnketSorular_Getir.UyeAnketID });
            }

            return View(view_Base_UyeAnketSorular_Getir);
        }
```

I hope I could tell you the problem.

Comment: How does your GET action method for this view looks like ?

Comment: What URL is created by your ActionLinks?

Comment: @ErikPhilips Url is "http://local???/Soru/Create/4". 4 is survey's id. And I want to save this id in the database with the Create method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass the SurveyId from the action method to the Question list view and use that when rendering the "create" link to add the surveyId as a querystring.

Looks like you do not have a view model, in that case,you may use ViewBag to pass this data.

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{ 
   var questions = db.Questions.Where(a=>a.SurveyId==id).ToList();
   ViewBag.SurveyId = id;
   return View(questions);
}
```

Now in your view, you may use this ViewBag item value to populate the RouteValueDictionary parameter for your `ActionLink` helper metod.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Yeni Soru", "Create",new { surveyId= ViewBag.SurveyId })
```

Assuming your `Create` action method has a parameter called `surveyId`

```
public ActionResult Create(int surveyId)
{
  // Use surveyId as needed ( Pass to view via ViewBag/ViewModel)
  // to do :return something
}
```

I also suggest looking into view models, instead of passing data via ViewBag/ViewData. It is more of a clean approach IMHO.

Comment: I could send an id with the viewbag to the question page. Thank you. But could you help a little bit more with Create?

[link](http://i.hizliresim.com/Bz6v1D.png)

how can i get id here?

Comment: Your create method should have a parameter as i explained in the answer.`Create(int surveyId)`

Comment: [link](http://i.hizliresim.com/PD60Ed.png)
Create Methods seems like this. I apologize but I did not know what to do.

Comment: I cannot see your image. But as i mentioned in the answer your create method should accept the survey id as parameter. Looks like you are struggling with the basics of MVC.  I suggest you read the basics of routing

Comment: I actually edited the question and added the create methods. Is it possible you can look?

Comment: Your Create(GET) action method looks fine. you can render a hidden input inside your form and that value will be submitted to your post method

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="@(ViewBag.UyeAnketID)">

How do I get this hidden value post method? Id is null when I run it like this .I apologize for keeping you busy

Comment: your `name` attribute value should match your method parameter name. So `<input type="hidden" name="UyeAnketID" value="@ViewBag.UyeAnketID" /> inside your `form`

Comment: My problem solved by you. Thank you very much. As soon as possible I'll ask you again, if My problem came out :)